# when i insert of description and img_url data behave differently?

Tags: php

PHP

```
$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) { 
  foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) { 

   $guid = $item->guid  ;
   $title = $item->title ;
   $url = $item->link;
   $description = (string)$item->description ;
   $date = $item->pubDate;
   $img_url = $item->enclosure['url'] ; 
   $category =  $item->category[1] ;  

   Insert($guid,$title,$description,$url,$date,$img_url) ;
}   


function Insert($g,$t,$des,$u,$d,$imgu) {
global $connection ;
echo $g,"<br>",$t,"<br>",$des,"<br>",$u,"<br>",$d,"<br>",$imgu,"<br>" ;
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO rssfeed (guid,title,description,url,date,img_url) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)" ;
$stmt = $connection->stmt_init() ;
$stmt->prepare($insert_sql) ;
$stmt->bind_param('isssss',$g,$t,$des,$u,$d,$imgu);
$stmt->execute() ;
 }
```

when i echo in function it shows clear output but in database in description  and img_url and url  coulmns have different data entry .both urls haven't full url information which as show in output file .

second question how can i sanitize the all this before input my db like dates ,url and tittle etc.

both images of output and database

[image: output of function]

[image: database input]

Comment: Why do you insert `<br>` HTML tags in your table?

Comment: @Jocelyn       Sorry for that , i echo that so i forget to remove but no change in still same problem